# like to invoke parameter-ed constructor at declaration and definition or afterwards any how of an array-of-a-class

Tags: c++, gnu

I have a following class and I am creating 1d array of that class. Class has two constructors. So when I create the array of class like 'Box b[5]',so the first constructor is getting called. What I like if there is a way I can initialize `length,breadth,height` at the time of declaration or definition or is there a way I can invoke the parameter-ed constructor of a class for same array object elements while/or after creating array `b[x]` (elements)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Box {
   public:
      // Constructor definition
      Box ()
      { 
        cout<<"without constructot"<<endl;
      } 
      Box(double l, double b = 2.0, double h = 2.0) {
         cout <<"Constructor called." << endl;
         length = l;
         breadth = b;
         height = h;
      }
      double Volume() {
         return length * breadth * height;
      }
      
   private:
      double length;     // Length of a box
      double breadth;    // Breadth of a box
      double height;     // Height of a box
};
int main()
{
    Box b[5];
}
```

Comment: I just dont want to add any function for initialization of member. Just want my constructor to initialize the class members of elements in array

Comment: `Box b[5] = {{0.5}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}, {7, 8, 9}};`?

Comment: @Jarod42 If I do `b+1` will it give me second element for example if I I do `Box *p=b[0];(p+1)=b[1];` and just go to do `cout<<(p+1)->height` will it be ok? Like C

Comment: Yes, even if `p[1].height` seems simpler to use.